# Issue with KubernetesPodOperator on GKE - PermissionDenied: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, service-accounts, airflow-2.x, google-secret-manager

I am running a Helm-based deployment of Airflow 2.5.3 on a kubernetes cluster on GCP. Almost everything is working except I can't seem to access the secretmanager on GCP using the service account that is setup for the cluster. My DAG launches a docker image using KubernetesPodOperator inside which is a python script that accesses some secrets like this:

```
client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()    

response = client.access_secret_version(request={
        "name": client.secret_version_path(PROJECT_ID, SECRET_ID, VERSION)})
```

I have previously executed this python script successfully using a DockerOperator with LocalExecutor. However, on my Kubernetes cluster, I get the following error when the job runs:

```
[2023-06-09, 00:33:54 UTC] {pod_manager.py:235} INFO - PermissionDenied: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
[2023-06-09, 00:33:54 UTC] {pod_manager.py:235} INFO - domain: "googleapis.com"
[2023-06-09, 00:33:54 UTC] {pod_manager.py:235} INFO - metadata {
[2023-06-09, 00:33:54 UTC] {pod_manager.py:235} INFO -   key: "service"
[2023-06-09, 00:33:54 UTC] {pod_manager.py:235} INFO -   value: "secretmanager.googleapis.com"
[2023-06-09, 00:33:54 UTC] {pod_manager.py:235} INFO - }
[2023-06-09, 00:33:54 UTC] {pod_manager.py:235} INFO - metadata {
[2023-06-09, 00:33:54 UTC] {pod_manager.py:235} INFO -   key: "method"
[2023-06-09, 00:33:54 UTC] {pod_manager.py:235} INFO -   value: "google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerService.AccessSecretVersion"
[2023-06-09, 00:33:54 UTC] {pod_manager.py:235} INFO - }
[2023-06-09, 00:33:54 UTC] {pod_manager.py:235} INFO - ]
```

I have checked and the service account has been granted access to the "Secret Manager Secret Accessor" role and I have setup the google connect in the airflow webserver ui
[as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvDNk.png), where I pasted the contents of the private key into the Keyfile json field. I get the exact same error if I just enter gibberish for the private key, so I am wondering is Airflow even recognizing it? Can anyone advise?

Comment: I learned that there is a difference between the IAM service account and a GKE service account. I followed the guide here https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#linux and once I bind the GKE service account to the IAM one I can now spin up a pod that can access google apis, the problem is I can't get airflow to do this - the pods that airflow launches for jobs (or component) do not have the right service account, I gather I should be able to somehow edit the helm chart to do this but how?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I can do this within the KubernetesPodOperator function itself by providing the `full_pod_spec`, the configuration I ended up using was:

```
k8s.V1Pod(metadata=k8s.V1ObjectMeta(name="test", namespace="airflow"),
    spec=k8s.V1PodSpec(
    containers = [k8s.V1Container(name="base")],
    service_account = "airflow-gke",
    service_account_name = "airflow-gke",
    node_selector={"iam.gke.io/gke-metadata-server-enabled": "true"}
    )
    )
```

passing this to the KubernetesPodOperator in lieu of a yaml let's me configure the pod as I wish and that solved the problem.